# Error publishing to Azure after upgrade to netcoreapp2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I upgraded my applications form net core 2 to net core 2.1.
I followed microsoft's upgrade instructions and locally all works fine.
However when i try to publish a dot net core web app with visual studio i get the message bellow like the upgrade did not happen at all:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error This version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.App is only compatible with the netcoreapp2.1 target framework. Please target netcoreapp2.1 or choose a version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.App compatible with netcoreapp2.0.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

...........

```
 <ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I know that i am not supposed to have a version in Microsoft.AspNetCore.App but visual studio 2017 (v15.7.3) does not recognize the referenced libraries otherwise. 
However this should not be a problem for publishing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you install the latest .NET Core SDK (2.1.300)? You can find it here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows. Tip: it does not ship with Visual Studio yet, you need to install it manually.

Comment: Yes, ofcourse. Otherwise it would not work locally. Locally everything runs fine. By the way also tried updating vs to v15.7.4. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that in .pubxml file the targetframework is set also and since I created the publish file with version 2.0 it never updated the xml:

```xml
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
```

Problem solved after editing it by hand to 2.1.

Comment: Strange how Visual Studio team slip those annoying details